# Django form condition to select only one field?

Tags: django, django-forms

Often I have situation in my app that I have several relations in the same model like:

```
SO =  models.OneToOneField(SOproduct,null=True, blank=True)
PO =  models.OneToOneField(PO,null=True, blank=True)
Produce =  models.OneToOneField(Produce,null=True, blank=True)
```

But I want to make sure that user will select only one. For example if there is SO then PO and Produce will remain empty and vise versa , when Produce selected PO and SO will remain empty.As well it is not mandatory that one of the fields will be selected

I can create 3 more tables to maintain relation but I don't want to do it.

Is there an elegant solution for this problem in Django ?

Comment: I think it's OK to have several `OneToOneField`. After all, you need to relationship anyway so I don't see what's the point for not having them.

Comment: you can use jquery to disable other fields when user fill one of these fields. On server side, you can use `clean` methods for form validation.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but perhaps defining a 3 way [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together)? `('SO', 'PO', 'Produce')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding validation for this in your `ModelForm` by overriding the `clean` method.

You should check if more than 1 field was selected. If it is, then you should raise `ValidationError` in your form.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()

        so = cleaned_data.get('SO') # get the value for 'SO'
        po = cleaned_data.get('PO') # get the value for 'PO'
        produce = cleaned_data.get('Produce') # get the value for 'Produce' 

        related_fields = [so, po, produce]
        related_fields_selected = [field for field in related_fields if field]

        # check if more than one related fields was selected 
        if len(related_fields_selected)>1: 
           raise forms.ValidationError('Please select only one value')

        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you can define a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together) meta option that requires a unique relation between the three, if more than one is attempted to be set a `ValidationError` would be raised.

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (('SO', 'PO', 'Produce'),)
```

> The ValidationError raised during model validation when the constraint is violated has the unique_together error code.